# Should i go for experience and then masters or masters directly.?

Tags: job-search, career-development

I have completed my Bachelor Of Computer Applications ( BCA ) and now I am confused. Should I apply for my Masters Of computer Applications ( MCA ) directly, or should I get some experience first and then go for masters ?

Comment: That entirely depends on where you are located. In my country, barely anyone enters the job market with just a bachelor's degree. Whereas in other countries, that's the norm and master's degrees are for education later down the road when you have experience.

Comment: Plus, the bigger question may be: What do you want to do with your life? It sounds like it's tech-oriented, in which case, perhaps, one of the [Tech Stack Exchanges](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) may be able to help you better? Especially since you may find this question closed soon because it may be considered too open-ended/opinion-based. Meanwhile, welcome to The Workplace Stack Exchange!

Comment: Have you tried career coaching? Most universities have career centers that'll help you explore your options and can give you personalized advice; many will also help you even if you've already graduated. Otherwise, there are generally affordable career coaches available in most cities. You *might* also try chat here. This kind of a question tends to be a poor fit for this site's format, though, because it's difficult for us to know enough about your circumstances to give useful advice and because it's not necessarily a helpful discussion for future readers.

Comment: My opinion is that it's better to work in the field for awhile first. First, that'll help you know if you even *like* working in the field. Secondly, you'll have a better sense of what you like to do and what you're good at; this is a major advantage for graduate school because you often have an opportunity to specialize more than you did as an undergraduate.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's best to do all the academic stuff in one go if you can. It means you stay in the learning/studying/writing up mode. Working is a big lifestyle change for many people, and sometimes it's difficult to jump straight back in to study.

Comment: By not following this advice, it took my way longer to get my degree....

Comment: @MisterPositive many get caught up in life and never go back

Comment: Okay i appreciate your answer.What if i want to get an experience while i am doing Masters of Computer Applications ( MCA ). ?

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, Studying master right after finishing degree is a terrible choice.

Working in a real environment is far different experience than educational environment. Thus getting few years of real work experience will help you to expand your horizon and help you to decide what to study next for your master.

Your expectations about your Master program will be much different when you have an industrial experience as compared to a fresh graduate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible in your country but here in france you can complete high level degrees in apprenticeship which gives you both.

It's a little harder because you're less time at school so you have to work at home , but you're at the same time working for a compagny so you're getting some experience.

I'm actually doing it and I think it's a realy great compromise.

I stopped studying and tried to get experience for 2 years and it's not that easy with low degrees and no first experience , apprenticeships are the best answer : You get the degrees AND experience.

But if that's not possible for you , you still can freelance while applying for your MCA.